# Loop through JSON from django model in template

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I don't know how to loop thorugh JSON object with javascripit in template (I know how to do it in HTML part but i need it to be in javascript). I figure out that if I safe my JSON object in variable like this:

```
<script>
let schedule = "{{ barber.schedule.schedule_day | safe}}"
</script>
```

it's saved as string type and I can't work with it, `schedule[0]` shows first character which is  `[`
I can't JSON.parse it either because error appears "Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2" i guess it's because my schedule has single quotes insted of dubble ones

this is how it my schedule looks when I console.log it

```
[{'start': 8, 'end': 10}, {'start': 12, 'end': 14}, {'start': 15, 'end': 16}]
```

this is how JSON from models looks like

```
{
   "schedule_day": [
      {
         "start": 8,
         "end": 10
      },
      {
         "start": 12,
         "end": 14
      },
      {
         "start": 15,
         "end": 16
      }
   ]
}
```

views.py

```
class Barber_schedule(DetailView):
    model = Barber
    context_object_name = 'barber'
```

models.py

```
schedule_template = '''
{
    "schedule_day": [
        {
            "start": 8,
            "end": 16
        }
    ]
}
'''
class Barber(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    start_time = models.IntegerField(default=8, validators=[MaxValueValidator(16), MinValueValidator(0)])
    JSON_schedule_template = json.loads(schedule_template)
    schedule = models.JSONField(default=JSON_schedule_template)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='barber_avatar', default='default.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript is not parsing the JSON string.

```
let schedule = JSON.parse("{{ barber.schedule.schedule_day | safe }}")
```

However, this will also not work because `schedule_day` is not a valid JSON string, it is just a string representation (`__str__()`) of the objects in your field.

The reason that field is objects, and not a string like it is in the database, is because the `JSONField` type automatically deserializes that database string to and from objects. Usually this is convenient since you want to iterate over the objects in the JSON in your view, however, in this case you just need the string to send to the front end.

The easiest solution would be to change the `JSONField` to a `TextField`. However, if you rely on the automatic deserialization elsewhere then you'll have to *re*-serialize the objects to a string in your view before they reach the template, then parse the JSON string into objects with Javascript.